# $A$ matrix is diagonalisable if $\exists S : S^{-1}AS $ is a diagonal matrix, how can I find S?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Per definition a matrix $A$ is diagonalisable if there exists a matrix S such that $S^{-1}AS$ is a diagonal matrix.

My question is how do I find the matrix $S$? Is it always the combination of the vectors that span the eigenspaces of the matrix $A$ or how can I find $S$?

Comment: Assuming $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, to construct a possible $S$, find $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$ and set them as the columns of $S$.

Comment: Aren't the eigenvectors of a matrix A always independent?

Comment: No. If $v$ is an eigenvector, so is $\lambda v$ and $\{v,\lambda v\}$ isn't a linearly independent set. I should also emphasize $\color{red}n$ vectors.

Comment: My problem is the following, I have the matrix : $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1+i \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1+i & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$. I have calculated the eigenvalues as : $\lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2 = 1+i, \lambda_3 = -1-i$, which yield to the eigenvectors: $v_1 = (0,1,0), v_2 = (1, \frac{2}{1+i},1),v_3 = (-1,0,1)$. So I get: $$S=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & \frac{2}{1+i} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$. Unfortunately when I invert this matrix and then calculate $S^{-1}AS$ I don't get a diagonal matrix, what am I doing wrong? I have checked the eigenvectors, they are correct.

Comment: I also used Mathematica for calculating the inverse and the matrix products, so there must be something wrong besides something computationally.

Comment: It has to work. Maybe you're misinserting something. I confirm that you're $S$ is correct. If you want me to pin point what exactly is wrong, you need to give me $S^{-1}$, the product $S^{-1}A$ and then $\left(S^{-1}A\right)S=$. If you care, note that $\frac{2}{1+i}=1-i$. **Edit:** Wolfram Alpha says your $S$ [works](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%7B%7B0%2C+1%2C+-1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1-i%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+1%2C+1%7D%7D%5E-1%29%7B%7B0%2C+0%2C+1%2Bi%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+0%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2Bi%2C+0%2C+0%7D%7D%7B%7B0%2C+1%2C+-1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1-i%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+1%2C+1%7D%7D).

Comment: Mathematica calculates the following: $$S^{-1} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{1}{i+1} & 1 & -\frac{1}{i+1} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ $$S^{-1}A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{i+1}{2} & 0 & \frac{i+1}{2} \\
 \frac{i+1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} (-i-1) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ $$S^{-1}AS = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & i+1 & \frac{1}{2} (-i-1)+\frac{i+1}{2} \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} (-i-1)+\frac{i+1}{2} & -i-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: And it is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Ok that was a little stupid on my part. I didn't even look at the elements, just noticed the matrix as a whole. I'm wondering why Mathematica doesn't simplify the two elements to zero though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. It would be good if you posted an answer to the question yourself so this doesn't come up as unanswered.